# Need Eclipse IDE Plugin Dev Help: Rename File Resource of the Active Editor, TextEditor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

From a plug-in in Eclipse, I have bound a key combination to attempt to use the Project Explorer refactor dialog to rename a file resource that is being edited by a TextEditor. The editor is the active selected view at the time. I am so far unsuccessful.

If I bind another key combination to the same command ID, that is "org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename", Then manually select the file resource in the Project Explorer and do the key sequence, the dialog does indeed present itself. Does this imply that I need to programatically give the Project Explorer focus?

Can anyone offer suggestions how I can programatically refactor/rename the resource associated with the active editor? I don't want to do "Save As" as this commits the change to disk and I don't want to force the user to do that yet.

The following is my test code called by the handler for the custom key binding command.

```
    public Object execute( ExecutionEvent event ) throws ExecutionException
    {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked( event );
        if( window == null ) return null;

        IWorkbenchPage workbench_page = window.getActivePage();
        if( workbench_page == null ) return null;

        IEditorPart active_editor = workbench_page.getActiveEditor();
        if( !( active_editor instanceof ITextEditor ) ) return null;

        // Not used here yet...
        StyledText styled_text = (StyledText)( (ITextEditor)active_editor).getAdapter( Control.class );
        Display display = styled_text.getDisplay();

        switch( event.getCommand().getId() )
        {
            case "test.commands.sampleCommand":
            {
                IViewPart view_part  = workbench_page.findView( "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer" );
                if( ( view_part != null ) && ( view_part instanceof ProjectExplorer ) )
                {
                    // Try and select the resource. This does not seem to do anything visually...
                    IPath path = ( (IPathEditorInput)active_editor.getEditorInput() ).getPath();
                    if( path == null ) return null;
                    ( (ISetSelectionTarget)view_part ).selectReveal( new StructuredSelection( path ) );

                    ICommandService command_service = ( (ProjectExplorer)view_part ).getViewSite().getService( ICommandService.class );
                    if( command_service == null ) return null;
                    Command file_rename_command = command_service.getCommand( IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_RENAME );

                    try
                    {
                        // Rename the selected resource.
                        file_rename_command.executeWithChecks( new ExecutionEvent() );
                    }
                    catch( NotDefinedException | NotEnabledException | NotHandledException exception )
                    {
                        log_error( "Did not work :", exception );
                        return null;
                    }

                    log_info( "Success :" + view_part.toString() );
                }

                return null;
            }

            default: return null;
        }
    }
```

The following is the resultant debug log output.

```
!ENTRY test 1 0 2019-12-19 09:47:06.902
!MESSAGE Did not work :
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:511)
    at test.Activator.execute(Activator.java:125)
    at test.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$2(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmKeyDown(Widget.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_KEYDOWN(Control.java:5146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_KEYDOWN(Canvas.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4820)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3583)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
```

Thanks and BR,
Ralph

PS,
Full discosure, I asked this question in the eclipse forums also.

Comment: Most editors don't provide a handler for rename. In fact editors need extra code added to deal with something else doing the rename - have you checked that the editor actually deals with a rename done elsewhere?

Comment: @greg-449, Thanks yes this is what I am trying to accomplish, i.e. adding rename capability to the editor. But I don't know enough about the whole eclipse IDE architecture and components to accomplish this. If I cannot find the answer, I will just have to start digging into the source code and learn that way.